# How to configure Appid Service with IBMid Identity provider

Tags: ibm-appid

I am searching to configure IBMid Provider using APPID (Bluemix) service, I found there a way by configuring SAML 2.0, but how to get the SAML details.

Answer (score 0):

IBMid do not have SAML interface. Please ping me on Slack/ST.